# Align uneven number of boxes two by two with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a list of boxes.
Whatever the width of the view, i want to pair them two by two.
The boxes will be equally separated like :

```
 ## For a view of 100 pixel width
 [ 10px <-> [box of 30px] <-> 10px <-> [box of 30px] <-> 10px ]
```

When the number of boxes is uneven, i'd like the last item to be aligned on the left.

This is a project for react-native, so the CSS flex property are limited

Here is my fiddle for now : https://jsfiddle.net/hf492cah/

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is the width and height of the box fixed or it should depend on the width? Do you want the gutter (space) between boxes to be fixed?

Comment: Hi. The size of the boxes are fixed. For the gutter, i don't really know. I was thinking having the same between left border / right border and between border, but fixed or not will make it. he easier the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [***calc()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) css to calculate the width and space between them according to view

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/hf492cah/1/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: flex;
}

.wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap li {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 100px;
  margin: calc(40px / 3) 0 0 calc(40px / 3);
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I ended up doing this as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content: flex-start;` or `justify-content: space-between;` to have non-complete row aligned to the left. To guarantee that boxes span the whole row you can set `flex-basis: 33%;`.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.wrap    { 
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}  
.wrap li {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
</ul>
```